# Newton's Method, and approximating parameters for Bézier curves.

Tags: approximation, bezier-curve, parametric

I've been wanting, for quite a while now, to polish up some source code I wrote for approximating arbitrary Bézier curves to given series of points. I managed to accomplish quite a bit, but I hit a road bump today while trying to write documentation for it.

I'm using Philip J. Schneider's "An Algorithm for Automatically Fitting Digitized Curves" (a copy can be found [here](http://iut-arles.univ-provence.fr/web/romain-raffin/sites/romain-raffin/IMG/pdf/PSchndeider_An_Algorithm_for_automatically_fitting_digitized_curves.pdf)) as source material, along with the C code that accompanies it (which can be downloaded [here](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems.zip) — it exists as `FitCurves.c` for the inclined inquirer) and an Objective-C port of the C code (which can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/andyfinnell/vectorbrush/src/40209d337251/VectorBrush/) — again, for the inclined). The thing that's tripping me up is documenting how the algorithm for refining parameters for a given Bézier curve works.

For reference, the gist of the algorithm is this (in pseudocode):

```
Function RefineParameters (Bézier curve, Point array, Parameter array)
  For every parameter in the list of parameters
    Use Newton's Method to refine the parameter, using the given points
```

There is enough input to be able to evaluate the Bézier curve at any given parameter (using De Casteljau's algorithm); the array of points is the array we want to fit a Bézier curve to — these are all 'correct' points, in the sense that we're trying to refine the parameters to match these points within some bounds of error; and the parameter array is the list of parameters (normalized from 0 to 1, of course), that we're trying to refine.

What trips me up is the explanation of Newton's Method, which is defined as follows (in terms of the Bézier function, $Q(t)$): $$t' = t - \frac{Q(t)}{Q'(t)}$$

Or, so I would assume. It would make sense that to refine the parameter we have, $t$, we'd use this formula. Using the given information we have, we can easily retrieve or calculate $t$, $Q(t)$, and $Q(t')$.

However, both code libraries (which provide completely correct code), do something different. The original C code provides no comments, and defines the formula to be: $$t' = t - \frac{(Q(t) - Q(t')) \cdot Q'(t)}{(Q(t) - Q(t')) \cdot Q''(t) + Q'(t)^2}$$

The Objective-C port is slightly more helpful by providing *some* comments, but not by much:

"Use Newton's Method to refine our parameter. In general, that formula is:" $$x' = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

"In our case:" $$f(x) = (Q(t) - Q(t')) \cdot Q'(t) = 0$$
"Where $Q'(t)$ is tangent to the curve at $Q(t)$ and orthogonal to [$Q(t) - Q(t')$]
Taking the derivative gives us:" $$f'(x) = (Q(t) - Q(t')) \cdot Q''(t) + Q'(t)^2$$

This leads us to the same result, and helps explain it only a little bit more. I half-understand the transition between the original form of Newton's Method and the second line: we've just solved for $f(x)$, and substituted $x$ with $Q(t)$. What I don't understand, though, is how or why $f'(x)$ is substituted with $Q'(t)$ (and if it makes sense to substitute them, why would we need to differentiate in order to find $f'(x)$ again later?).

Knowing this algorithm works, I tried to work backwards and perhaps meet in the middle. We're looking to refine some parameter $t$ so that we can't refine it any more (meaning $f(x)$ becomes $0$). Solving for $f(x)$, we get $f(x) = (Q(t) - Q(t')) \cdot f'(x)$, which is zero if $f'(x)$ is orthogonal to $(Q(t) - Q(t'))$. However, it stops making sense for me right there — why is it legal to just replace $f'(x)$ with $Q'(t)$? I understand that makes them orthogonal, but if that were valid, why the need to solve for $f'(x)$ later?

I could leave the code as-is, but I want to document it. Being able to explain a concept to others helps you understand it so much better yourself. Any help with this?

Comment: Well, you're solving for $t$ and not $Q(t)$, no? The $t$ you are looking for satisfies the implicit equation $(Q(t) - Q(t')) \cdot Q'(t) = 0$; you take that as the numerator, and then you differentiate with respect to $t$ and then take that as a denominator. Newton-Raphson was always intended for approximating the solution $x$ to the equation $f(x)=0$.

Comment: In short: the two versions of Newton-Raphson are concerned with two different equations, that happen to have the same solution $t^\prime$.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your comment. Any chance you can write that up as an answer? I understand what you're getting at — but it just hasn't 'clicked' with me yet.

Comment: @J.M. As I was getting into bed last night, it clicked and made total sense. It seems I just wasn't thinking about the application of Newton's Method the right way. $(Q(t) - P) \cdot Q'(t)$ is the function we're using to get zeroes (or $t$s), and for whatever reason, I didn't get that until I read and thought over your answer. Thanks!

Comment: May I encourage you to answer your own question, then? :)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Like [rubber duck problem solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html), I've managed to figure this out in my head (with the help of J.M.), where it just wasn't making much sense. I was going about the problem the wrong way.

The more accurate the parameters we get, the closer we get to $$(Q(t) - P) \cdot Q'(t) = 0$$ or in other words, the vector formed by the difference between our Bézier curve evaluated at a parameter $t$ that we want to refine and the real point it corresponds to becomes increasingly perpendicular to the slope of the Bézier curve at that parameter. When we reach the right $t$, they're perfectly perpendicular.

That's why $f(t) = (Q(t) - P) \cdot Q'(t) = 0$ (of which we take the derivative to get our solution). We're trying to better approximate the values of parameters *for which this is true*. Every iteration of the method will get us closer to the real parameters.

Didn't make much sense to me before (likely because I was bashing my head in for hours trying to figure it out), but now it's pretty clear.